# Is this a true inequality over multinomial parameters?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, probability-inequalities

Let $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ be the multinomial parameters sampled from a Dirichlet distribution. Assume $\bar{p_1},\ldots,\bar{p}_k$ be the mean of Dirichlet distribution. Then,
$$Pr( \sum_{i}|p_i-\bar{p}_i|\le \epsilon) \ge \prod_{i} Pr (|p_i-\bar{p}_i|\le \epsilon/k)$$

Comment: is this under self-study?

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, this is. Do you know any reference that talks about this? Does this inequality have any name?